# Unable to access anonymously uploaded S3 objects when authenticated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket with this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Uploading and deleting objects works from any web client without any authentication e.g. cURL.

However if I'm authenticated as an IAM user (without any policy or even the `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy), I get 403 errors when trying to access (`GET`) the objects uploaded **anonymously**. Accessing other objects uploaded **non-anonymously** (e.g. through the S3 console) can be accessed. What is happening?

To recap:

- anonymous user:

  - can upload files into the bucket
  - can download files from the bucket upload by themselves or by any other user
- authenticated IAM user:

  - can upload files into the bucket
  - can download files from the bucket upload by themselves
  - **cannot download files uploaded by an anonymous user**

PS: According to the IAM Policy Simulator, the anonymously uploaded files should be downloadable by the IAM user.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually [expected](https://gist.github.com/jareware/d7a817a08e9eae51a7ea) [behavior](http://www.itsolut.com/chrismusings/2009/07/07/how-to-setup-any-user-put-to-s3-and-private-get/):

> It is not possible to have an anonymous Put to S3 and a private Get. Turns out the anonymous user owns the Object.

The mistake I made was assuming that setting a policy using the `*` principal would mean "everyone", while actually in only means "the anonymous user". And objects "owned" by a user (which includes the special anonymous user) cannot be accessed by another user (unless you were to set a policy on the object itself I assume). The fact the other user can "see" the object because it has the right to "list" the bucket doesn't mean it can read its content.

Comment: +1 for finding the solution.  I suspect that `*` doesn't restrict to the only anonymous user, but that in actuality I or anyone else could *also* upload to your bucket with my credentials and then I would own the object.  If I didn't give you permission to read it, you couldn't -- all you could do would be to delete it, since I owned the object but you own the bucket.  There's not much in the way of a good case for allowing anonymous uploads to S3.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that even if anonymous upload is allowed on the bucket, you wouldn't be able to upload if authenticated. Because only the anonymous user is allowed. That's certainly what happens when downloading.